# Display the result of the POST request in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to create a page that displays the data received after hitting an API,

my response JSON looks like this

```
{
  “Total_count”: 100,
  "queryColumns": [
    {
      “title”:”done”,
      “count”:120,
      “percentage” :48 
    },
    {
      “title”:”partially_done”,
      “count”:30,
      “percentage” : 12
    },
    {
      “title”:”Not Done”,
      “count”:100,
      “percentage” : 40
    }
  ]
}
```

Everytime I hit the API I might get a different result,
I am trying to display this data in the app.

My flutter code looks like below,

and  I am calling another widgets i.e buildRadialProgressBar inside the build() which receiving the arguements it generates the circular view .

in below for buildRadialProgressBar i am passing data directly like (GIVING THE DUMMY DATA)
\

```
buildRadialProgressBar(
  progressPercent: 0.48,
  color: Colors.green,
  count: 120,
  title: 'done',
)
```

build widget looks like this,

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: LimitedBox(
      maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.30,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              buildSubscriberTile(context),
              buildRadialProgressBar(
                context: context,
                progressPercent: 0.48,
                color: Colors.green,
                count: 120,
                title: 'done',
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              buildRadialProgressBar(
                context: context,
                progressPercent: 0.12,
                color: Colors.red,
                count: 30,
                title: 'Not done',
              ),
              buildRadialProgressBar(
                context: context,
                progressPercent: 0.40,
                color: Colors.purple,
                count: 100,
                title: 'partially done',
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

what i am trying to do is rather than giving dummy values , I want it to take from the result of the POST request. and display,

for the dummy data its everything is working fine(display part) but I dont know how to initialize those parameters inside the buildRadialProgressBar with the result of the json output.

remaining code as follows

```dart
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  reportList = getReport(); //Iam callling the API
}

getReport() async {
  http.Response response =
    await http.get(PostURL, headers: {"token": "$token"});
  switch (response.statusCode) {
    case 200:
      String reportList = response.body;
      var collection = json.decode(reportList);
      return collection;
      break;
    case 403:
    case 401:
      return null;
    default:
      return 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options for passing data such as using the Provider package, BLoC pattern, etc., but the simpler method might be fine for what you're trying to do.

In your `initState` you're calling the API for retrieving the data. Once the data is retrieved, you can pass it to the child widgets (your `buildRadialProgressBar`) to have them build the data appropriately. You can trigger the rebuild of those child widgets using `setState`. In your example, it would be something like :

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  getReport();
}

getReport() async {
  http.Response response =
    await http.get(PostURL, headers: {"token": "$token"});
  if(!mounted) {
    return;
  }
  switch (response.statusCode) {
    case 200:
      String reportList = response.body;
      var collection = json.decode(reportList);
      setState(() {
        _data = collection;
      });
      break;
    case 403:
    case 401:
      setState(() {
        _errorMessage = 'Forbidden';
      });
      break;
    default:
      setState(() {
        _errorMessage = 'Unexpected error';
      });
      break;
  }
}
```

This will cause the widget to be rebuilt once the data is retrieved. Also check that when you actually get the result of the response the widget is not already removed from the widget tree (why I check the "mounted" before processing the data).

Then, in setting up your radial widgets, just pass the data from the `_data` field and you can even show a progress indicator while `_data` is still null. For example:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if (_data == null) {
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  } else {
    return buildRadialProgressBar(
      progressPercent: _data[0]['percentage'],
      color: Colors.red,
      count: _data[0]['count'],
      title: _data[0]['title'],
    );
  }
}
```

Passing the context to the `buildRadialProgressBar` widget is typically not necessary as the widget will have its own `BuildContext` in its build function.

Comment: thanks for the changes, but one thing I am not able to access the data inside the json output, I am facing difficulty while parsing it, I am not getting how that _data[0]['count'] points to the count in that json,for testing in my project I declared list i.e  final _questions = const [
    {

"Total_count": 100,

"queryColumns": [
                {
                                "title":"done",
                                "count":120,
                                "percentage" :48 
                }, ]; but i am not able to access the fields inside it I am not doing a post req

Comment: If your JSON is as you posted at the top, you indeed need to do something slightly differently. I was using the array as an example, but with the specific JSON you should be able to do _data['queryColumns'] which will give you the array and then _data['queryColumns'][0] which will give you the first element.